# Why are the two sets not equal?

Tags: clojure

The question is about `not=`:

```
Clojure> (doc not=)
---------------------
Cloure.core/not=
    ([x] [x y] [x y & more])
    Same as (not (= obj1 obj2))

Clojure> (not= [1 2 3] [1 2 3])
false
Clojure> (not= '(1 2 3) '(1 2 3))
false
Clojure> (not= #(1 2 3) #(1 2 3))
true
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking why the 3rd case is true?

Comment: Actually, `#(1 2 3)` is an anonymous function. Do you mean `#{1 2 3}`?

Comment: sorry for my foolish question :)

Answer (score 14):

Sets use braces

```
user=> (not= #(1 2 3) #(1 2 3))
true
user=> (not= #{1 2 3} #{1 2 3})    
false
```

Answer (score 4):

just for reference the # character is the ["dispatch macro"](http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Macro%20characters) in the clojure reader.
it tells the reader to treat the expression folowing it specially. So far as I know it is
the only reader macro defined in clojure.

- `#( )` define a function. short for `(fn [< optional-args >] ...)`
- `#" "` define a regular expression
- `#'`  reference a var it's self instead of the value in a var.
- `#{ }` define a set.
- `#_` don't read the next statement. this is like a super comment, it is more through than a comment but the distinction is not commonly used.

Comment: six year later update, it's no longer the only reader macro, we have `^` now as well, which ads metadata

Answer (score 1):

Others have commented that `#(1 2 3)` is not a set, but rather a function (that raises an error when invoked). The reason that `#(1 2 3)` is not equal to `#(1 2 3)` is that each invocation of `#(...)` creates a new anonymous function, and each new function belongs to a new Java class:

```
user=> (class #(1 2 3))
user$eval60$fn__61
user=> (class #(1 2 3))
user$eval64$fn__65
```

These classes have an `equals` method that doesn't consider objects of the other classes equal, even though they happen to have been defined in the same way. The method is in fact inherited from `java.lang.Object`:

```
user=> (for [m (.getMethods (class #(1 2 3)))
             :when (= (.getName m) "equals")]
         (.getDeclaringClass m))
(java.lang.Object)
```